# How to setup postgresql database parameters to deploy a Spring boot rest application

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

it's the first time i try to deploy one of my projects on real server, so i'm completely not sure of what i'm doing.
I built a Maven multi module Rest Api, in java with Spring, that connect to a postgresql database.
When i work locally i just set the database properties in application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

which works very well.
But when i try to make a deployment, the provider service (clever-cloud for me)
give me credentials for database as environments variables

```
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_HOST=
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_DB=
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_USER=
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_PORT=
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_PASSWORD=
POSTGRESQL_ADDON_URI=
```

so i tried to add them in my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = ${POSTGRESQL_ADDON_URI}
spring.datasource.username = ${POSTGRESQL_ADDON_USER}
spring.datasource.password = ${POSTGRESQL_ADDON_PASSWORD}
```

and in intelli-j configuration, i set these environment variabbles with the good values.
If i run the appplication it's ok,
but if i do a mvn clean install to be sure that my project is ok,
i'm getting errors:

```
nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${POSTGRESQL_ADDON_URI}
```

So any idea of what am i doing wrong ? Probably a lot of stuff i guess! Thanks

Comment: The variables in IntelliJ are only valid for the run configuration. Obviously when you are running maven those don't apply. Looks like a test is bootstrapping the application, and I highly doubt you want a test to utilize these properties. Add a specific `application.properties` for test, which contains hardcoded URLs for the test database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It make sense, though i'm not very confortable with maven configuration. I will check how to setup properties for test ! Thanks

Comment: Why would you need maven? Just add an `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` with hardcoded values for testing. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Thats exactly what i just did and it worked ! Sorry i really don't master these topics yet ! But it works. Thanks a lot !